# export and import selected entries from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario:

```
database on host1: rhel6sales
table:  customer
particular customer i want to export, and then import to another host: select * from customer where handle = 'CARDD2';
```

I can use mysqldump to copy the whole "customer" table, but that is not what i want. I want to be able to only export and then import CARDD2

Now CARDD2 might have joins and key constraints with other tables, so if i just export and import customer, of just CARDD2, how would i handle the other tables, would they data be exported automatically ? so when i import it would check and implement the joins and key constraints in the database i am importing to ? assuming the two databases have same schema